# RVM | Obtrusive gems in the global gemset

Tags: rvm

Every time I install a Ruby version using RVM, the program also installs some of the default gems to the global gemset.

For example, after installing the version 2.1.0 of Ruby:

```
€ rvm install 2.1.0
```

I get the following default gems:

```
€ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.3)
bundler (1.5.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
gem-wrappers (1.2.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
```

As it turned out, in addition to installing rubies RVM always installs the gems which is specified in the file `~/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems` to the global gemset ([source](http://rvm.io/gemsets/initial)). Some of the aforementioned gems really are in the file. However, when I remove all the gems from it, the program anyway installs the following:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.3)
gem-wrappers (1.2.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
```

Why RVM installs all of those gems? What is the necessity of their presence in the system? How can I specify for RVM not to install them after installing a Ruby version?

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7

RVM 1.25.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this gems are part of ruby distribution:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
```

this gem is part of rvm and is required for rvm to function properly:

```
gem-wrappers (1.2.3)
```